# Mariadb and excel 2013 connection string

Tags: excel, mariadb

I have a working connectionn on Excel 2003, I have tried the same connection string on Excel 2013 and it won't connect the error returned is:

```
    [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified.
```

The database connection details are indical on both systems, I've tested the connection on each system using the "Test DSN" button in the "ODBC Data Source Administrator" "System DSN" tab.

```
    Connection successfully established

    Server information 10.1.9-MariaDB
```

I've also tried pinging the database server from both systems and both systems ping successfully.

The connection string for the Excel 2013 system:

```
    Driver={MariaDB ODBC 2.0 Driver};Server=demo;Port=3306;Database=dbname;User=username;Password=password;Option=3
```

My VB routine to connect:

```
    Const CELL_DRIVER As String = "B2"
    Const CELL_HOST As String = "B3"
    Const CELL_PORT As String = "B4"
    Const CELL_USER As String = "B5"
    Const CELL_PASSWORD As String = "B6"
    Const CELL_DATABASE As String = "B7"
    Dim conn As ADODB.Connection
    '--
    ' Attempts to create database connection
    ' Returns:
    '   Database connection or Nothing if an error occurs
    '--
    Private Function DBconnect() As ADODB.Connection
        On Error GoTo errHandler

        If False Then
    errHandler:
            MsgBox Err.Description, vbCritical, "ERROR in connect"
            Set conn = Nothing
            Set DBconnect = Nothing
            Exit Function
        End If            
        If Not conn Is Nothing Then
            Set DBconnect = conn
            Exit Function
        End If
        Dim strDSN As String, objSheet As Worksheet
        Set objSheet = Application.Sheets("Database")
        strDSN = "Driver={" & objSheet.Range(CELL_DRIVER) & "}" _
               & ";Server=" & objSheet.Range(CELL_HOST) _
               & ";Port=" & objSheet.Range(CELL_PORT) _
               & ";Database=" & objSheet.Range(CELL_DATABASE) _
               & ";User=" & objSheet.Range(CELL_USER) _
               & ";Password=" & objSheet.Range(CELL_PASSWORD) _
               & ";Option=3"
        Set conn = New ADODB.Connection
        conn.ConnectionString = strDSN
        conn.Open
        Set DBconnect = conn
    End Function#
```

I've added port 3306 to the Firewall.  I've also tried adding a User DSN.  I've also been through this page... http://helpdeskgeek.com/office-tips/excel-to-mysql/ still no success.

I've downloaded the latest ODBC driver for MariaDB 2.0, uninstalled original 1.0 driver and installed latest, sadly the same behaviour everything connects except Excel.

I tried using the Workbook Connection wizard, that errors too.  Suggestions welcome.  The latest error message displayed in Excel:

```
    [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] The specified DSN contains an architectyure mismatch between the Driver and Application
```

I downloaded the 64bit version of the OBCD driver as the host system is running Windows 7 Professional 64 bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The system is a 64bit system, however with the 64bit ODBC driver installed Excel couldn't connect.

I installed the 32bit ODBC driver for MariaDB and tried the connection again, now it works.

NOTE: I did not uninstall the original 64 bit driver and I did nothing to the existing ODBC configuration leaving the set-up referencing the 64 bit driver.  All I did was install the 32 bit driver and now it works.